# Talent Buddy Tweets per second

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to solve this question from talent buddy.
http://www.talentbuddy.co/challenge/52a9121cc8a6c2dc91481f8d5233cc274af0110af382f40f

My code compiles and runs for small input, but is giving wrong ans for the following input-
http://tb-eval4.talentbuddy.co/5411559648d3e7eb5100024191810645628720530000.html

My Code is as follows -

```
import java.util.*;
class MyClass {

public void tweets_per_second(Integer[] tps, Integer k) {
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq =new PriorityQueue<Integer>(k, new Comparator<Integer>(){
        public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2){
            if (i1.intValue()< i2.intValue()){
                return 1;
            }
            else if(i1.intValue() ==i2.intValue()){
                return 0;
            }
            else {
                return -1;
            }
        }

    });
    for(int i=0;i<tps.length;i++){
        if (pq.size()<=k){
        pq.add(tps[i]);
        System.out.println(pq.peek());    
        }
        else{
            pq.remove(tps[i-k]);
             pq.add(tps[i]);   
            System.out.println(pq.peek()); 
        }

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass t = new MyClass();
    Integer[] tps = {6,9,4,7,4,1};
    t.tweets_per_second(tps, 3);
}
```

}

Can someone please let me know what am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is entirely correct. At the end of the page you can see the following:

```
Error: your code didn't finish in less than 2 seconds.
```

Which tells you all you need to know.

As to why your code is slow - while using PriorityQueue or any built in collections etc is overall a good idea, it is very much not so in this case. I don't want to make educated guesses about how it's implemented, but one of `add, remove, peek` is not O(1) and eats up your time.